# a for loop to generate multiple data frames in python

Tags: python

I am new to python and trying to clean up my code by using a function which generates as many data frames as I desire. I want to get df1, df2, df3, etc. out by reading in different lists (one, two, three, etc.). The variable "Input" is always the same. Here is the code:

Thx!

## convert list into data frame

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(one, columns=[(Input.cell(0, 0)).value + 'A',
                                 (Input.cell(0, 0)).value + 'B',
                                 (Input.cell(0, 2)).value + 'A',
                                 (Input.cell(0, 2)).value + 'B',
                                 (Input.cell(0, 3)).value + 'A',
                                 (Input.cell(0, 3)).value + 'B',
                                 (Input.cell(0, 4)).value + 'A',
                                 (Input.cell(0, 4)).value + 'B',
                                 (Input.cell(0, 5)).value + 'A',
                                 (Input.cell(0, 5)).value + 'B',
                                 (Input.cell(0, 6)).value + 'A',
                                 (Input.cell(0, 6)).value + 'B',
                                 (Input.cell(0, 7)).value + 'A',
                                 (Input.cell(0, 7)).value + 'B',
                                 (Input.cell(0, 8)).value + 'A',
                                 (Input.cell(0, 8)).value + 'B',
                                 'pos1', 'mut1'])

# replacement of '' to NaN
df1 = df1.replace('', np.nan, regex=True)
# calculate differences between individual clones
for i in range(2, 9):
    df1[(Input.cell(0, i)).value + '_dAB'] = diff(df1[(Input.cell(0, i))
                                                  .value + 'A'],
                                                  df1[(Input.cell(0, i))
                                                  .value + 'B'])
```

Comment: Whenever things that should have been declared in a loop (or list comprehension) declared manually by duplicating lines - a fairy dies...

Comment: And a catgirl dies too. Timo, use [for](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html) and [range](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range).

Comment: thanks guys!! - and sorry for having killed fairies and catgirls for the last couple of weeks;)) However, I am still looking for a function which does the above, because I have to do this serveral times (df1, df2, df3, etc.). Also, would it be possible to create a for loop for columns=[Input.cell....

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(number_of_your_desire):
    df1[(Input.cell(0, i)).value + '_dAB'] = diff(df1[(Input.cell(0, 2)).value + 'A'], df1[(Input.cell(0, i)).value + 'B'])
```